# Why is this local recrusive C++ lambda so terrible slow?

Tags: c++, performance, lambda

For understandig I'm using a local lambda with recursive call (tail recursive). Running this (for example on http://cpp.sh/ or https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/) it always shows that the lambda call is massiv slowlier than the other solutions.

#### And my question is why this ?

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>
#include <functional>
 
//tail recursive lamda
long long int Factorial5(long long int n)
{ 
  std::function<long long int(long long int,long long int)> aux
     = [&aux](long long int n, long long int acc)
  { 
    return n < 1 ? acc : aux(n - 1, acc * n);
  };
  return aux(n,1);
}
 
//tail recursive inline class
long long int Factorial6(long long int n)
{ 
  class aux {
    public: inline static long long int tail(long long int n, long long int acc)
    { 
      return n < 1 ? acc : tail(n - 1, acc * n);
    }
  };
  return aux::tail(n,1);
}


int main()
{
    int v = 55;
    {
        auto t1 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
        auto result = Factorial5(v);
        auto t2 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
        std::chrono::duration<double, std::milli> ms = t2 - t1;
        std::cout << std::fixed << "lamda(5)\tresult " << result
                  << " took " << ms.count() << " ms\n";
    }
    {
        auto t1 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
        auto result = Factorial6(v);
        auto t2 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
        std::chrono::duration<double, std::milli> ms = t2 - t1;
        std::cout << std::fixed << "inner class(6)\tresult " << result
                  << " took " << ms.count() << " ms\n";
    }
}
```

Outputs:

```
lamda(5)        result 6711489344688881664 took 0.076737 ms
inner class(6)  result 6711489344688881664 took 0.000140 ms
```

Comment: `std::function` uses type erasure so it is expensive to use an does not inline as well as functors do

Comment: There are a number of problems with your profiling approach here. For starters, you are using a compile-time constant input (which the compiler can potentially constant-fold, reducing the cost to zero), and you are measuring a tiny time interval only once. That's not a fair comparison in any way (and not indicative of real-world performance in either case).

Comment: @YSC You can't do that. To build recursive lambdas like that you would need a Y-combinator.

Comment: Oh, and `55!` overflows a `long long int` _several_ times.

Comment: @MaxLanghof You're right ^^

Answer (score 7):

A lambda is not a `std::function`. Each lambda has its own unique type. It roughly look like this:

```
struct /* unnamed */ {
    auto operator()(long long int n, long long int acc) const
    { 
        return n < 1 ? acc : aux(n - 1, acc * n);
    }
} aux{};
```

So in principle, a lambda is really fast, as fast as any function or non virtual member function.

The slowness comes from `std::function`, which is a type erasure wrapper around a lambda. It transform a function call to a virtual call, and potentially dynamically allocate the lambda. That is costly and prevent inlining.

To create a recursive lambda, you must use C++14 generic lambdas and send the lambda to itself:

```
auto aux = [](auto aux, long long int n, long long int acc) -> long long int
{ 
  return n < 1 ? acc : aux(aux, n - 1, acc * n);
};

return aux(aux, n, 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

For what it's worth, the result on my system was:

```
lamda(5)        result 6711489344688881664 took 0.003501 ms
inner class(6)  result 6711489344688881664 took 0.002312 ms
```

Which is far less drastic, though still measurable difference.

The reason for the difference is that the function does hardly any work, but there are very, very many function calls. As such, any function call overhead dominates the result. `std::function` has overhead, and this shows in the measurement.

---

Note that the example program overflows `long long`, so the results are meaningless because the behaviour is entirely undefined. The correct result should be about 6.689503e+198. In theory, the UB invalidates results of the runtime measurement as well, though not necessarily in practice.

Answer (score 0):

The lambda is an object of an unnamed type, which calls `operator()` of a different object (the `std::function`), which calls the lambda, ...

That is, there is a mutual recursion and indirections through objects, which makes this very difficult to optimise.
Your code is more or less equivalent to this (I've shortened the type to `int`):

```
struct Aux;

struct Fun
{
    const Aux& aux;
    Fun(const Aux& aux) : aux(aux) {}
    int work(int n, int acc) const;
};

struct Aux
{
    const Fun& fun;
    Aux(const Fun& fun) : fun(fun) {}
    int actual_work(int n, int acc) const
    {
        return n < 1 ? acc : fun.work(n-1, acc*n);
    }
};

int Fun::work(int n, int acc) const
{
    return aux.actual_work(n, acc);
}

int factorial5(int n)
{
    Fun fun = Aux(fun);
    return fun.work(n, 1);
}
```

Which makes it clearer that there is a lot of invisible stuff going on.